# задержка вывода AT команд в библиотеке pyserial python

Tags: python, pyserial

кратко говоря, этот код позволяет вводить АТ команды в модем. Проблема в том, что, к примеру, я ввожу просто AT и мне должно ответить "ОК", но оно сначала отвечает "CME ERROR", а потом, когда я второй раз нажимаю enter, уже выводит ОК. Так с абсолютно любой командой, модем у меня fibocom L860GL 16. Что делать, чтобы такого не было?
Вот код:

```
import serial
import re

import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for port in ports:
        ports2 = port.__str__()
        ports3 = ports2.split('\n')
        for i in ports3:
            if i.find('acm2') != -1:
                com = re.findall(r'\w{1,100}', i)
                for el in com[:1]:
                    comport = str(el)
ser = serial.Serial(port=comport, baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=0, xonxoff=False,rtscts=True, writeTimeout=None, dsrdtr=False, interCharTimeout=None)
while True:
    commmm = input()
    ser.write(commmm.encode('ascii') + '\r'.encode('ascii'))
    out = ser.read(500)
    out1 = bytes.decode(out, encoding='ascii')
    print(out1)
```

Comment: еще раз - вопрос в чем? "что делать", чтобы что?

Comment: шоб такого не было

Comment: Попробуйте двойной `'\r\r'` делать после каждой команды, а не одинарный

Comment: `'\r\n'` ещё можно попробовать

Comment: Так а номер ошибки какой?

Comment: не помогло ()(()

Comment: ошибки ни какой нет, там тупо задержка которая описана в проблеме моей